# Order-first in xs bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have used order-sm-first how I can use this for old xs Extra small
<576px ?

order-first work in all query

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 order-sm-first">
```

Comment: `xs` was dropped in bootstrap 4, maybe you are able to use it like this -> `order-first`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for `order-first`. Only use of the actual `-xs` infix was dropped. The xs breakpoint (<576px) still exist but now it's the default or implied breakpoint so you don't need to specifically use `-xs`.

Also know that `order-first` really means 1st on "xs and up" so it needs to be overridden by a larger breakpoint as needed...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            1 (first on sm and up)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 order-first order-sm-last">
            2 (first on xs)
        </div>
    </div><!--/row-->
</div><!--container-->
```

https://codeply.com/go/WMnCWPikCh

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are wondering for order-0 utility from bootstrap. Bootstrap4 is mobile first so ideally you should write your HTML in a way that is supposed to happen in Mobile first. Then for other views change the order of your HTMl element.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="d-flex flex-nowrap bd-highlight">
  <div class="order-xl-3 p-2 bd-highlight">First flex item</div>
  <div class="order-xl-2 p-2 bd-highlight">Second flex item</div>
  <div class="order-xl-1 p-2 bd-highlight">Third flex item</div>
</div>
```